# Insert Query for Dynamically created textboxes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have dynamically generated text-box for which i need to write an insert query into my `SQL server 2005` database.
The problem is when i write the insert query i can't include the text-box names as the text-box will be generated run time.

I tried using the following logic:

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I WISH TO GENERATE DYNAMIC TEXTBOXES AND THEN A DYNAMIC SQL QUERY.**

```
   String str=//will contain a data fetched from all the textboxes generated dynamically and will be seprated using a ','(as in an insert statement).
```

This string `str` will be directly passed on to the insert query so that all the values will be taken in directly.

But the logic does not work.

Please help..

Comment: I need to work this out....tried in several ways but didn't work. Please help..

Comment: Is the number of maximum textboxes fixed?If not then how will you decide the number of columns of the table?

Comment: @RaviSingh: No sir. The number will be decided at run time. I can get the count of the number of columns in a table using a combobox and generate the same number of textboxes dynamically

Comment: @user : Then create a new table with fields : `ID int,textboxName(If required) varchar(),value varchar()`. This `Id` field will reference the id from the current table. This will solve the issue.

Comment: @RaviSingh: No sir this wont solve my problem. As I wish to generate an insert query in my existing table which will also include the newly generated columns dynamically entered for which new textboxes are created.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points

1. Your method leaves you open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. This is a bad thing. You should use a sqlCommand object to execute the SQL, using parameter objects to pass in the values to insert, this will guard against SQL Injection attacks.
2. Name your textboxes after each column in the table your inserting into.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sir...Yes SQL injection may be an issue. But to start with I cannot navigate through dynamic insert into query..

Comment: Please don't call me Sir, I work for a living. Do you know the name of table you're inserting into? Do you know the names of the columns on the table?

Comment: Then why can;t you name the text boxes after the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of your text boxes as they are generated.

```
List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
```

...

```
TextBox DynamicBox1 = new TextBox();
...
TextBoxes.Add(DynamicBox1);
```

Then if you have the names of your columns somewhere

```
string Columns = "@col0, @col1, @col2"; //etc

string Query = @"INSERT INTO [Table]
                 (" + Columns.Replace("@", "") + ")
                 VALUES (" + Columns+ ")";
```

using a paramaterized command

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);

for (int i=0; i<TextBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col" + i, TextBoxes[i].Text);
}

Connection.Open()
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connection.Close()
```

I have not added in error handling